# Taking "Inline CSS" and add into "CSS file" via Joomla - How?

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

I am using the "JJ Social Slider" for Joomla to add Social Media Buttons. My problem is that the plugin automatically adds a chunk of inline CSS (see below) into my html page and I couldn't find a way how to prevent that or at least put it into an external CSS file. I would like to keep all CSS external.

Please help!

Inline CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">ul#jj_sl_navigation li a {background-color:#00c70a;text-align:left;color:#ffffff !important}ul#jj_sl_navigation .custom1 a:hover{background-color:#000000}ul#jj_sl_navigation .custom2 a:hover{background-color:#000000}ul#jj_sl_navigation .custom3 a:hover{background-color:#000000}ul#jj_sl_navigation .custom4 a:hover{background-color:#000000}ul#jj_sl_navigation .custom5 a:hover{background-color:#000000}ul#jj_sl_navigation {left:0;top:300px}ul#jj_sl_navigation li:hover {margin-left:0}ul#jj_sl_navigation li a {padding:11px 0 11px 10px;margin-left:-2px}ul#jj_sl_navigation .facebook a {background-position:144px 50%;background-image:url(http://localhost/media/mod_social_slider/icons/facebook-black.png)}ul#jj_sl_navigation .twitter a {background-position:144px 50%;background-image:url(http://localhost/media/mod_social_slider/icons/twitter-black.png)}ul#jj_sl_navigation .google a {background-position:144px 50%;background-image:url(http://localhost/media/mod_social_slider/icons/google-black.png)}ul#jj_sl_navigation .myspace a {background-position:144px 50%;background-image:url(http://localhost/media/mod_social_slider/icons/myspace-black.png)}ul#jj_sl_navigation .youtube a {background-position:144px 50%;background-image:url(http://localhost/media/mod_social_slider/icons/youtube-black.png)}ul#jj_sl_navigation .linkedin a {background-position:144px 50%;background-image:url(http://localhost/media/mod_social_slider/icons/linkedin-black.png)}ul#jj_sl_navigation .steam a {background-position:144px 50%;background-image:url(http://localhost/media/mod_social_slider/icons/steam-black.png)}ul#jj_sl_navigation .lastfm a {background-position:144px 50%;background-image:url(http://localhost/media/mod_social_slider/icons/lastfm-black.png)}ul#jj_sl_navigation .pinterest a {background-position:144px 50%;background-image:url(http://localhost/media/mod_social_slider/icons/pinterest-black.png)}ul#jj_sl_navigation .soundcloud a {background-position:144px 50%;background-image:url(http://localhost/media/mod_social_slider/icons/soundcloud-black.png)}ul#jj_sl_navigation .tumblr a {background-position:144px 50%;background-image:url(http://localhost/media/mod_social_slider/icons/tumblr-black.png)}ul#jj_sl_navigation .github a {background-position:144px 50%;background-image:url(http://localhost/media/mod_social_slider/icons/github-black.png)}ul#jj_sl_navigation .flickr a {background-position:144px 50%;background-image:url(http://localhost/media/mod_social_slider/icons/flickr-black.png)}ul#jj_sl_navigation .rss a {background-position:144px 50%;background-image:url(http://localhost/media/mod_social_slider/icons/rss-black.png)}ul#jj_sl_navigation .vimeo a {background-position:144px 50%;background-image:url(http://localhost/media/mod_social_slider/icons/vimeo-black.png)}ul#jj_sl_navigation .custom1 a {background-position:144px 50%;background-image:url(http://localhost/media/mod_social_slider/icons/icon.png)}ul#jj_sl_navigation .custom2 a {background-position:144px 50%;background-image:url(http://localhost/media/mod_social_slider/icons/icon.png)}ul#jj_sl_navigation .custom3 a {background-position:144px 50%;background-image:url(http://localhost/media/mod_social_slider/icons/icon.png)}ul#jj_sl_navigation .custom4 a {background-position:144px 50%;background-image:url(http://localhost/media/mod_social_slider/icons/icon.png)}ul#jj_sl_navigation .custom5 a {background-position:144px 50%;background-image:url(http://localhost/media/mod_social_slider/icons/icon.png)}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,.site-title{font-family:'Open Sans',sans-serif}body.site {border-top:3px solid #e0d319;background-color:#002ee6 }a {color:#e0d319}.navbar-inner,.nav-list >.active >a,.nav-list >.active >a:hover,.dropdown-menu li >a:hover,.dropdown-menu .active >a,.dropdown-menu .active >a:hover,.nav-pills >.active >a,.nav-pills >.active >a:hover,.btn-primary {background:#e0d319}.navbar-inner {-moz-box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.25),inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1),inset 0 30px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);-webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.25),inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1),inset 0 30px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.25),inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1),inset 0 30px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2)}</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am actually the developer of JJ Social Slider. The reason we do this is because this part of the CSS requires values that are based on parameter values and php variables cannot be called in a CSS file.

There **are** some methods to apply this as a separate file, however we used a style declaration for a cleaner coding flow

Comment: As someone who have been using Joomla on a daily basis for 6 years, thank you